# Resampling a EEG Signal with non-constant sampling frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a EEG Signal with a non-constant sampling frequency as shown in the image below.

[image: EEG Signal with a non-constant sampling frequency]

I'm trying to do resampling on the EEG Signal to achieve a constant sampling frequency so that it can be better used for further analysis.

[image: EEG Signal with a constant sampling frequency]

Right now, I'm breaking the signal into time frames of 1 second each, and resampling them using the [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) function to get a constant sampling frequency. However, the resulting EEG Signal seems to be incorrect, with weird fluctuations at the connecting points.

[image: Resampled EEG Signal]

I don't think that I'm doing this correctly, so if it is possible, can someone provide a better suggestion or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

**Existing code (executed in a for loop that goes through the entire EEG signal in time frames of 1 second each):**

```
% Calculate resampling factors p & q
% Fs(currSecond) gives the number of samples within that time frame of 1 second
% nFS is the target sampling frequency (constant) to be achieved for each time frame

[p, q] = rat(nFs/Fs(currSecond), 0.0000000001);

% Calculate the end of data to be resampled
endSample = currSample + Fs(currSecond) - 1;

% Resample EEG data
EEG_Data_Resampled = ...
    resample(EEG_Data_Trimmed(currSample : endSample, 1:4), p, q, 0);

% Store resampled EEG data
nCombinedData(startRow : endRow, 2:5) = num2cell(EEG_Data_Resampled);

% Update starting sample for next iteration
currSample = currSample + Fs(currSecond);
```

**Edit:** Changed the `resample` function to use a n value of 0

```
% If you let n = 0, resample performs a nearest-neighbor interpolation
% Resample EEG data
    EEG_Data_Resampled = ...
        resample(EEG_Data_Trimmed(currSample : endSample, 1:4), p, q, 0);
```

And it seems to give me better resampled data, but I'm still not sure if the features of the original EEG Signal is being preserved for the resampled version.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a time vector accompanying your samples?  IIRC, `resample` assumes a consistent sampling interval, which you haven't got.  Or maybe you do have periodic sampling, but not an integer number of blocks per second.

Comment: There is a time vector that comes with the EEG data samples. I used the time data to calculate how many data samples there are in each second.

Comment: How many samples are in any particular clock second is quite useless.  What resolution for your timestamps?  Are multiple consecutive samples marked with the exact same time?

Comment: Each row of EEG data comes with the corresponding time data, which is in Unix time. The time data is converted to a Matlab datetime object as shown here, http://imgur.com/kxyUXBf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resample will only convert from one fixed sample rate to another.  To resample from a non-constant sample rate, you must know the time of each of your original samples.  If you know those times as `t_orig_sec` you can interpolate your original signal onto a new time base (`t_new_sec`) via the `interp1` command.  What type of interpolation you use (`linear`, `spline`, etc) will affect the type of distortions or harmonics generated by the interpolation process.

I recommend something like:

```
%given: t_orig_sec and eeg_data
%interpolate to a new, fixed sample rate: fs

fs = 250;  %new sample rate in Hz
dt_sec = 1/fs;
t_new_sec = [t_orig_sec(1):dt_sec:t_orig_sec(end)]  %new time vector
new_eeg_data = interp1(t_orig_sec, eeg_data, t_new_sec, 'spline');
```

The bigger question, though, is whether your eeg signal really is being sampled unevenly.  Nearly every data acquisition system meant for continuous signals (like EEG) sample at a constant rate.  If that data is not arriving at your PC at a constant rate, it could be due to delays in your data acquisition system pushing the data out across the serial communications line, or it could be due to delays in your operating system servicing the received serial communications.

Before resampling your signal, I would strongly suggest that you confirm that your system really is sampling unevenly.  I would inject a known, constant-frequency signal into your EEG system (you'll likely need to divide down your injected signal with resistors to get a much lower voltage).  Then, I would look at the data that is recorded for your injected signal.  Assume that the system has a constant sample rate and look at a spectrogram of the recorded signal.  If the frequency of the recorded signal is stable, then your EEG system is correctly recording at a constant sample rate.  If the frequency of the recorded signal varies, then you will have confirmed that your system has a varying sample rate.

If it varies, you have justification to re-interpolate your signal.  To do the re-inpterpolation, you'll need a very good "clock" to tell you when each of the samples has arrived.  I'm fairly sure that clock built into the PC is not going to give you time stamps with the accuracy that you need...the clock value might appear to have good precision (ie, lots of digits) but it doesn't mean that it is accurate in that it gives you the exact time immediately upon the arrival of each sample.  I think that there's a lot of variability in there.  That variability will probably mean that your re-interpolation will damage the signal as much as it will repair the signal.

Comment: now resample function can deal with non uniform sampling